# Weird behavior when running unit tests testing Fluentvalidation in NancyFx

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nancy, fluentvalidation

I am seeing some strange things in my unit test suite these days.

I have a REST API created in NancyFX. I recently started implementing a new style of validation using FluentValidation.

My test suite has about 1000 tests at the moment, and of these I now have around 10 tests for the first Fluent Validation. This is where it gets weird. As I was writing these tests everything was fine. But as soon as I ran my whole test suite all the Fluent Validation tests failed.

When I looked at the error it told me:

```
"No model validator factory could be located. Please ensure that you have an appropriate validation package installed, such as one of the Nancy.Validation packages."
```

But the assemblies are referenced from my test library and when I run the tests on their own they work fine and are green.

I use the Resharper test runner. Thr validator is invoked using BindAndValidate and I am invoking endpoints usin the nancy test browser.

The next bit of weird behavior is that these tests run fine on Team City.

I am at a loss. I can't figure out why it cannot resolve those assembly references.

Answer (score 1):

What happened here was that I have two test projects. One for integration tests, and one for unit tests. Apparently the unit test project also instantiates a test browser object. I wasn't aware that someone had used the browser object and essentially put an integration test into the unit test project.

The unit test project ran tests before the integration tests. Since the unit test project didn't have references to the FluentValidation DLLs, the TinyIOC container didn't pick up the validation classes. The unit test project didn't invoke any of the BindAndValidation paths, so it wasn't a problem... but it became a problem once the integration tests ran.

So what I saw was not the actual problem, but a symptom.